# Is the Use of \vstretch Causing Confusion with the Footnotemark and Its Associated Text? (A Partial Correction but Still Not Entirely Right)

Tags: footnotes

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vstretch{1.4}{\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{THIS IS THE FIRST STRETCHED SENTENCE}}}}} \vskip 8pt \hskip 42pt  \vstretch{1.4}{\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{THIS IS THE SECOND.\footnotemark}}}}}
\footnotetext{How come the footnotemark here is not an asterisk?}
\end{center}

\vskip 15pt

\Large
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Here's an unstretched sentence.\footnotemark}}
\footnotetext{The footnotemark and footnote for the unstretched sentence.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

[image]

Notice that the second stretched sentence has an associated footnote as indicated by the asterisk. However, the actual footnote is indicated by a different symbol.

The unstretched sentence also indicates a footnotemark which corresponds to the actual footnote. But I am puzzled as to why an asterisk is being used again.

Is the `\vstretch` command causing these problems? If so, how may I correct it? i.e., how may I get the first footnote to indicate an asterisk, and the dagger to appear as the footnotemark in the unstretched sentence and its associated footnote?

**UPDATE**

Per Ul. Fischer comment, I am posting the log file:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
I have since discovered that If I relocate the `\footnotemark` command as such:

```
\vstretch{1.4}{\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{THIS IS THE FIRST STRETCHED SENTENCE}}}}} \vskip 8pt \hskip 42pt  \vstretch{1.4}{\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{THIS IS THE SECOND.}}}}}\footnotemark
```

The footnote marks and the text are produced correctly---though the first footnotemark (asterisk) is comparatively small and is not appropriately elevated:

[image]

[image]

REVISED QUESTION: With the said correction, how may I increase the size of the first footnotemark asterisk and elevate it to an appropriate position at the end of the sentence? Thank you.

Comment: I get an asterisk. Show your log-file.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I have just posted it as an update to the question. Thank you.

Comment: that is not the log *file* but a screenshot of the sumary of your editor. Check the tab which says "log file", or search for the file on your disk.

Comment: @Ulrike On my computer, that is what comes up under log and also, under log file; there is a tab called ``issues'' it is very long and not postable.  I will, perhaps, see if I can figure out what the problem may be from it. Thanks.

Comment: the log file is a real file, with the extension .log. You can simply open it in your editor and then copy & paste the content, or put it somewhere for download.